# Looking for an Online Password Manager

Tags: web-applications, passwords

I'm looking for a web password manager. It should have groups and users support and be free if it's possible.
Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Online password manager [PassPack](http://www.passpack.com/) very promising. They've got free account too, but for one shared user.

Comment: Thank you, but users support is essencial
Anyway, I'll take a look